# How to find the command line of a process only if the process is from current user

Tags: perl, bash, process, pid, ps

I have the following situation:
A perl script read a file where a application wrote it's `pid`, and tries to kill it.
But the problem is that I don't want to kill another process so I check if current process with the recorded PID has the same command line. If so, the application could be killed.

The following blues script find out the cmdline:

```
$PIDCMDLINE = `ps -p $PID -o cmd`;
```

The problem is that if another instance for another user is up, maybe on the same sid, it would be killed because it will return a valid command line, and I don't want that behaviour.

How can I restrict ps -p to search only current users processes (no, simple `ps` doesn't count, because `-p nullify` the default effect of ps)

Thank you!

Comment: If you are not root, you cannot kill other users' processes.

Comment: If you're on a Linux or other system with `/proc` available, then you can check just for the uid of `/proc/$PID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to check both command and user for the certain PID:

```
ps -p <PID> -o user,cmd --columns 1000 | grep `whoami`
```

Adding a 'grep' according to the comment.

Comment: Could I just tell ps that I'm interested only in current user, without finding it first and then passing it to ps? Otherwise, good answer. Thank you.

Comment: You can just add a simple grep:
ps -p <PID> -o user,cmd --columns 1000 | grep `whoami`

Comment: @imapollo Rather than using a pipe to `grep` the output, you could say: `ps -u $(whoami) -p <PID> -o cmd`

Comment: :( In this situation -p <PID> is ignored and all cmdlines from current user are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

May be a little awkward, but what about this:

```
$PIDCMDLINE = ps -p $PID -o user,command | grep `whoami` | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

Comment: It's a bit too complicated for the simple purpose of finding out the command line. Also 3 new processes are created, and I don't afford this luxury.

Comment: @nucandrei Yes adding an `awk` is more expensive than splitting the `user command` output in the main script.